# How to achieve fluid width using 960 Grid System?

Tags: css, 960.gs

I have used 960gs to generate the layout for a web application, however the development process was done on my 15″ laptop throughout. Viewing the application on a 22″ monitor, it seems very small, i.e. its width remains fixed regardless of the monitor size.

Is this a limitation of the 960gs, or a problem in my own CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @oezi mentioned, that's just how the 960gs works.

Having said that, you can achieve what you desire by using **[a variant on the 960gs](http://www.designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/)** that's based on percentage units rather than pixels, and generates a fluid layout instead of a fixed one. It is linked in the bottom of the [960gs homepage](http://960.gs/), under *Derivatives*.

***Note:** You could, and certainly should alter the code to your needs. For extra motivation, please read [Matt Ward's post](http://blog.echoenduring.com/2011/03/03/why-i-use-css-frameworks/) describing CSS frameworks as **"A tool, not a crutch"**.*

Comment: So what would i do, replace the my current 960 css with this 1?

Comment: well, it will solve your problem, but it's up to you. it'll work the same and you should be able to switch the CSS and forget about it, you can see how i did it [here](http://123completed.com/).

Answer (score 1):

as the website says, your site will be `960px` wide, regardles of the users resolution - on a 22"-monitor (full-hd?) thats just 1/2 of the screen width... thats how it works.

> **Essence**
>
> [...] based on a width of
>   960 pixels.

what you could try to do is to [create several grid-sizes](http://grids.heroku.com/) and use [media-querys](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to include the one thats fits best to the actual resolution.